# I want to use a trained keras model to make predictions on a handwritten text in an Image

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

After training, I loaded up my model and passed in the CTC Layer, I downloaded a test Image online and called model.predict(x=image) but I kept getting errors about the image's shape.
[image: first image]

[image: second image]

I then tried to run a reshape function on the image to fit the input layer (128, 32, 1), and I got another error. I'll appreciate any advice on how to run a prediction on a real image, gotten from an API endpoint. Thank you so much.

Below you will find the function I tried to use to [image: reshape function]reshape the image.

And the error I got while reshaping
[image: reshape error]

Comment: Post code snippets not images.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Answer (score 1):

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

image_size tuple contains three elements but you are receiving two.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o34Su.png